# Problem to return list which contains items from rest api

Tags: java, android

I've got a problem with a method in Android which should return a list of items which are received from rest api. I am able to debug these items in that method - because I wrote declaration of this method in the onCreate method. But the problem occurs once I try to add these items (in that method) to the list, so the  method could return these. I receive an error like:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

the method which should return items:

```
public List<Categories> displayDataaaa(List<Categories> categoriesList) {

    this.categoriesList = new ArrayList<Categories>();
    /
    String cat_name = "";

    // this.categoriesList.add(new Categories(1,"lkajsdflk"));
    this.categoriesList.add(new Categories(1, categoriesList.get(0).getCategoriesName()));


    for (int i = 0; i < categoriesList.size(); i++) {
         cat_name = categoriesList.get(i).getCategoriesName();
      //    this.categoriesList.add(new Categories(i, cat_name));
        Log.d("displayDataaaaa-cat_name", "displayDataaaaa-cat_name" + cat_name);

        this.categoriesList.addAll(categoriesList);
    }
 //   this.categoriesList.add(new Categories(1, cat_name));

    return this.categoriesList;
}
```

Could I ask you for some hint, please?
Thank you.

Log:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dev4passion.partyj10/dev4passion.partyj10.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
    at dev4passion.partyj10.MainActivity.displayDataaaa(MainActivity.java:189)
    at dev4passion.partyj10.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:94)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: On which line does the exception occur?

Comment: Please provide log

Comment: When I try to add an item to the list, so this:     this.categoriesList.add(new Categories(1, categoriesList.get(0).getCategoriesName()));

Comment: @Shivendra Tiwari I added the log

Comment: As your logs suggest the size of the list is 0 and you are trying to retrieve data from the list. Debug and inspect the argument of the method

Comment: @Shivendra Tiwari debuging this:    for (int i = 0; i < categoriesList.size(); i++) {
             cat_name = categoriesList.get(i).getCategoriesName();
          //    this.categoriesList.add(new Categories(i, cat_name));
            Log.d("displayDataaaaa-cat_name", "displayDataaaaa-cat_name" + cat_name);

Comment: @Shivendra Tiwari 2020-08-08 22:57:10.212 2059-2160/dev4passion.partyj10 D/displayDataaaaa-cat_name: displayDataaaaa-cat_nameItem1
2020-08-08 22:57:10.212 2059-2160/dev4passion.partyj10 D/displayDataaaaa-cat_name: displayDataaaaa-cat_nameItem2
2020-08-08 22:57:10.212 2059-2160/dev4passion.partyj10 D/displayDataaaaa-cat_name: displayDataaaaa-cat_nameItem3
2020-08-08 22:57:10.212 2059-2160/dev4passion.partyj10 D/displayDataaaaa-cat_name: displayDataaaaa-cat_nameItem4

Comment: Nice !! Things are getting logged. Why is it like in every iteration you are just adding same list again and again

Comment: This is just the example thing, when I try to add an item from the list which is from the api, the app throws that error ( but the list from api is not empty ). The same thing is when I try just to return simply the list from the api - app throws that error.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.categoriesList.add(new Categories(1, categoriesList.get(0).getCategoriesName()));
```

This is your problem line. `categoriesList.get(0)` will throw an exception when `categoriesList` is empty.

Comment: The thing is that categoriesList is not empty, I can debug the items inside of the method ( declaring the method's name in onCreate method - I can see what's happening in the method, where I debug items of the list which I received from the api ), but cannot add any of the items to the list so I could return the method.